# react hook for setting the document title does not work on ssr

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following hook for setting the document title of a react website that is initially rendered on the server:

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react';

export const useDocumentTitle = (title: string): void => {
  useEffect(() => {
    document.title = title;
  }, [title]);
};
```

This does not run on the server and only in the browser.  Is there any way to get this hook to run on the server?

Comment: How do you render on the server? next uses Header component to set title on the server.

Comment: @HMR great idea, I'll check that out

Comment: UseEffect doesn't work for server-side rendering. What we can try is to make your code run once it gets loaded on the client-side.

Comment: Do you use any serverside rendering framework? or just perform normal serverside rendering

Comment: Dear @dagda1, please share your SSR implementation on somewhere like CodeSandBox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`document.title` can only be applied on `client side rendering` since you need access to dom to be able to update the title. On a server side rendering you don't have access to document or window and hence need to provide the html with meta tags for each page or route

There are couple of solutions to handling `document.title` with server-side rendering

- **you could make use of existing libraries (if you are wiling to use one) like [`react-helmet`](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet) that allow you much more control of meta tags**

Example usage

```
const App= ({title, children}) => {
   return (
    <React.Fragment>
       <Helmet>
          <title>{title}</title>
        </Helmet>
        {/* Other logic here */ }
     </React.Fragment>
   )
}
```

Now if you wish to implement a generic component, you could write a component like an HOC

```
const TitleWrapper = ({title, children}) => {
   return (
    <React.Fragment>
       <Helmet>
          <title>{title}</title>
        </Helmet>
        {children}
     </React.Fragment>
   )
}
```

Now you can use it with your component like

```
const App = () => (
   <TitleWrapper title={"Title page"}>
       {/* Some components here */}
  </TitleWrapper>
)
```

Now while rendeing you can write it like

```
app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
  const app = renderToString(<App />);
  const helmet = Helmet.renderStatic();

  res.send(formatHTML(app, helmet));
});

app.listen(8000);

function formatHTML(appStr, helmet) {
  return `
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        ${helmet.title.toString()}
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="root">
          ${ appStr }
        </div>
        <script src="./bundle.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
  `
}
```

- **Now considering that a library just to update `document.title` might be too much of a dependency. Another solution here is to write your own component that handle server side rendering but also allows you to add title in your document on client side.**

Before writing a custom component like this you must note that you might need to handle multiple instances of components in the same view. To go with the easiest approach you can choose to get the last active instance to render the document title

You must also note that as of now here is not alternative to `componentWillMount` on serverSide

The below code is inspire by [`react-document-title`](https://github.com/gaearon/react-document-title) by @DanAbramov

```
class AddDocumentTitle extends React.Component {
   static mountedInstances = []; // keep track of mounted instances. Being a prototype this won't be reinitializd for each instance

   static renderStatic() {
       // Will be used on serverSide
        const inst = AddDocumentTitle.getCurrentActiveInstance();
        AddDocumentTitle.mountedInstances.splice(0)// remove all instance since on serverside componentWillUnmount won't run
        if(inst) {
            return inst.props.title; // return the title props
        }
   }

   static getCurrentActiveInstance() {
      const length = AddDocumentTitle.mountedInstances.length;
      if (length > 0) {
        return AddDocumentTitle.mountedInstances[length - 1];
      }
      return null;
   }


   static updateDocumentTitle() {
      if (typeof document === 'undefined') {
        // for serverside this will be undefined
        return;
      }
      // code that will only run on clientSide
      const activeInstance = AddDocumentTitle.getActiveInstance();
      if (activeInstance) {
        document.title = activeInstance.props.title;
      }
    }

    static defaultProps = {
        title: ''
    }

    constructor(props) {
         super(props);
         AddDocumentTitle.mountedInstances.push(this); // Add instance to mounted instance
         AddDocumentTitle.updateDocumentTitle(); // This will update it on serverSide
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
      if (this.isActive() && prevProps.title !== this.props.title) {
         // Update title if this instance is still the active instance and props title changed
         AddDocumentTitle.updateDocumentTitle();
      }
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
       // Remove this instance from instance list and update documentTitle according to the now active instance
       const index = AddDocumentTitle.mountedInstances.indexOf(this);
       AddDocumentTitle.mountedInstances.splice(index, 1);
       AddDocumentTitle.updateDocumentTitle();
    }

    isActive() {
       return this === DocumentTitle.getActiveInstance();
    }

    render() {
       if (this.props.children) {
           return React.Children.only(this.props.children);
       } else {
           return null;
       }
    }
}
```

Now that we have written our class component, we can use it in the following manner

```
const App = () => (
   <AddDocumentTitle title={"Title page"}>
       {/* Some components here */}
  </AddDocumentTitle >
)
```

Now on `serverSide` you need to call `renderToStatic` and embed this obtained title into HTML page template just like we did with Helmet

```
app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
  const app = renderToString(<App />);
  const title= AddDocumentTitle.renderStatic();

  res.send(formatHTML(app, title));
});

app.listen(8000);

function formatHTML(appStr, title) {
  return `
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        ${title}
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="root">
          ${ appStr }
        </div>
        <script src="./bundle.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
  `
}
```

I hope this information is helpful for you